# Horizontal equivalent of zz in vim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

If I press `zz` in vim, my screen/view will center vertically on the cursor position.

How can I do the same, but horizontally? Is there a vim command for that?

Comment: Do you mean moving the cursor to the middle of the current line?

Comment: @Kusalananda i mean moving the view so that the cursor is at the center of the screen, without changing the cursors actual position

Comment: How would that work if the current line is empty, for example?

Answer (score 12):

There's no single Vim command, but you can combine [`zs`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/scroll.txt.html#zs) with [`zH`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/scroll.txt.html#zH): Scroll to position the cursor at the left side of the screen, then scroll half a screenwidth to the right.

I have this mapping in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
" Horizontally center cursor position.
" Does not move the cursor itself (except for 'sidescrolloff' at the window
" border).
nnoremap <silent> z. :<C-u>normal! zszH<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks, I came here looking for `zs`. E.g., in IdeaVim, when using using `n` to go to a search term on a long line that's off screen to the right; `zs` on its own brings it onto the screen. In regular vim I use soft wrap so it's not an issue.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a direct answer to the question, but potentially a different solution to the underlying problem. In my case, the problem was for really long lines, the right side falls off the screen and the cursor ends up far on the right side.

```
:set sidescrolloff=<number of characters>
```

Interestingly, if you just put a giant number in here, it appears to cap it up to the middle of your screen. In this way, you never have to do a "zz" equivalent because the cursor is always centered horizontally on the screen (except when you're hitting the left edge).

Just for completeness, if you wanted the equivalent vertically, you use

```
:set scrolloff=<number of lines>
```